# While creating a test script in selenium i am getting following error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package javaapplication3;
import java.lang.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
/**
 *
 * @author kipl74
 */
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String baseurl="www.google.com";

        driver.get(baseurl);

    }
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting following errors. How to resolve it?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'comp74', ip: '192.168.0.74', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Session ID: 0282db64-b28b-4c3b-ba83-26fe06bd46a3
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=26.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:23)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'comp74', ip: '192.168.0.74', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.get(file:///C:/Users/kipl74/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2500892407184382634webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8720)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/kipl74/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2500892407184382634webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/kipl74/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2500892407184382634webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/kipl74/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2500892407184382634webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Method `get` requires the protocol as part of the URL.**

Change:

```
String baseurl = "www.google.com";
```

To:

```
String baseurl = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your calling method to open the browser. I believe you have written code like this:

```
driver.get("Url"); //Incorrect Code
```

Correct should be like:

```
driver.get(Url);// Correct Code
```

Comment: Your belief is plain wrong. OP has used `driver.get(baseurl)`, as clearly and explicitly stated in the question!!!